# Does dirt sink or rise in boiling water?

Tags: food-processing, sunchokes

I need to clean a lot of sunchokes (for winter freezing), and was wondering if the dirt will fall off the tubers if I boil them long enough, before sending them through a potato ricer.

Comment: Some will sink, some will rise.  In the presence of convection such as you get when boiling, much of it will remain in the water

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your intention is just cleaning the sun chokes, just soak them in clean water for couple of hours. The dirt will loosen up. Then rub them off with your fingers. They will easily come off. Again rinse them in clean water, and repeat till they are completely clean. Boiling will not work for cleaning them. It will rather completely cook them or par boil them depending upon the time you boil. So if you just want to clean them, then don't boil them.

Answer (score 8):

No, you can't clean your tubers by boiling them, you'll just end up cooking them in mud, which will stick to them when you take them out. You need to clean them first.